# Stickerview Matrix Scale

Tags: android, matrix, scale

I wanted to scale with the stickerview in the matrix, but the result was as follows.

[image]

When my request matrix is ​​returned, the scale will not be distorted like the picture.
[image]
how can I do that?

Comment: My Code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926816/12872602

Comment: are you got any solution ?