# How do I change the rotated matrix scale in Android Studio from 4 sides?

Tags: android

I wanted to scale the matrix on the stickerview from four sides, what I wanted was to be as in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7W2N.jpg)

But that was not what I wanted and the tag was broken like the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEIav.jpg)

My Code: [How to change view's size from 4 side in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806006/how-to-change-views-size-from-4-side-in-android/53926816#53926816)

Comment: are you got any solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no solution yet